# How to use score system between two def function

Tags: python

So I just wanna ask that how to get score system between two def function ao if made a score system in first def function and I made a score of 150 how to continue score in second def function from 150 only I tried the global command but it didn't work pls give me solution
Here's my code

```
def play():
    money=100
    print("you have been given 100 coins for free at start")
    money=money-25
    number=(input("What will you choose 7up , 7down , 7: "))
    if number=="7up":
        import random 
        print("the random generated number is:")
        gen=(random.randrange(1,12))
        print(gen)
        if gen > (7):
            print("the random generated number is greater than 7.")
            print("congratulation u got 50 coins")
            money=money+50
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
        elif gen < (7):
            print("the random generated number is not greater than 7.")
            print("congratulation u got nothing")
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
        elif gen == (7):
            print("the random generated number is 7.")
            print("congratulation u got nothing")
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
    if number=="7down":
        import random 
        print("the random generated number is:")
        gen=(random.randrange(1,12))
        print(gen)
        if gen > (7):
            print("the random generated number is greater than 7.")
            print("congratulation u got nothng")
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
        elif gen < (7):
            print("the random generated number is not greater than 7.")
            print("congratulation u got 50 coins")
            money=money+50
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
        elif gen == (7):
            print("the random generated number is 7.")
            print("congratulation u got nothing")
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
    if number == "7":
        import random 
        print("the random generated number is:")
        gen=(random.randrange(1,12))
        print(gen)
        if gen > (7):
            print("the random generated number is greater than 7.")
            print("congratulation u got nothng")
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
        elif gen < (7):
            print("the random generated number is not greater than 7.")
            print("congratulation u got nothng")
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
        elif gen == (7):
            print("the random generated number is 7.Wow lucky.")
            print("congratulation u got 100 coins")
            money=money+100
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
def playagain():
    Money= global money
    return (Money)
```

Comment: How are you calling these functions? The code you've shown us won't run them because they're not called, and how and in what order they're called is going to determine how they need to communicate to one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use the `global` keyword in the function where it is created and then use it in the other function, using your examples directly:

Execute the `play()` function first and then execute `playagain()`

```
def play():
    global money
    money=100
    print("you have been given 100 coins for free at start")
    money=money-25
    number=(input("What will you choose 7up , 7down , 7: "))
    if number=="7up":
        import random 
        print("the random generated number is:")
        gen=(random.randrange(1,12))
        print(gen)
        if gen > (7):
            print("the random generated number is greater than 7.")
            print("congratulation u got 50 coins")
            money=money+50
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
        elif gen < (7):
            print("the random generated number is not greater than 7.")
            print("congratulation u got nothing")
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
        elif gen == (7):
            print("the random generated number is 7.")
            print("congratulation u got nothing")
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
    if number=="7down":
        import random 
        print("the random generated number is:")
        gen=(random.randrange(1,12))
        print(gen)
        if gen > (7):
            print("the random generated number is greater than 7.")
            print("congratulation u got nothng")
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
        elif gen < (7):
            print("the random generated number is not greater than 7.")
            print("congratulation u got 50 coins")
            money=money+50
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
        elif gen == (7):
            print("the random generated number is 7.")
            print("congratulation u got nothing")
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
    if number == "7":
        import random 
        print("the random generated number is:")
        gen=(random.randrange(1,12))
        print(gen)
        if gen > (7):
            print("the random generated number is greater than 7.")
            print("congratulation u got nothng")
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
        elif gen < (7):
            print("the random generated number is not greater than 7.")
            print("congratulation u got nothng")
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
        elif gen == (7):
            print("the random generated number is 7.Wow lucky.")
            print("congratulation u got 100 coins")
            money=money+100
            print("Your current money is")
            return (money)
def playagain():
    Money= money
    return (Money)
```